# Helping me understand the formal definition of ODE's

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definition

Currently I am writing a project at Uni, where we define Ordinary differential equations (ODE's). However, I seem to have some trouble comprehending the definition. It's taken from Lecture notes on Ordinary Differential Equations. Annual Foundation School, IIT Kanpur, Dec.3-28, 2007. By S. Sivaji Ganesh.

It basically states a hyphothesis first that says:

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be a be a domain and $\mathbb{I} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an interval. Let $F : \mathbb{I} × \Omega → \mathbb{R}$ be a function
defined by $(x, z, z_1, . . . z_n) \mapsto F(x, z, z_1, . . . z_n)$ such that $F$ is not a constant function in the variable $z_n$.

Then we have the definition:

Assume the above hypothesis. An ordinary differential equation of order
$n$ is defined by the relation
$$F(x,y,y',y'',...,y^{(n)}) = 0$$
where $y^{(n)}$ stands for $n$'th derivative of unknown function $x \mapsto y(x)$ with respect to the independent variable $x$.

Now I understand the difference between $\mapsto$ and $\to$. And I understand, that $\subseteq$ means subset and what that is.

What I don't understand is why $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, since, as far as I know, $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a vector space of $n+1$ dimensions. Since I don't understand that, our cartesian product doesn't really make sense for me aswell.

Lastly, I don't understand why $F$ can't be a constant function in the variable $z_n$, my guess would be, it's because we can't solve / there is no solution to:
$$F(x,y,y',y'',...,y^{(n)}) = k$$
for any given constant $k$.

Sorry about multiple questions in one question, I hope that someone can help me along to understanding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
Since k.defaoite already gave an answer I will focus on your question regarding $\Omega \subseteq \R^{n+1}$. It is not entirely clear to me what you are having trouble with, so I'll just guess what might help you.

Indeed $\R^{n+1}$ is an $n+1$-dimensional vector space. So you can think of it as the plane (this would be $n=1$) and then $\Omega$ is a domain (usually this means an open connected subset). So it might be the disc with radius 1 (without the boundary).
Or it might be something more funky. This is basically where you want the function to be defined. We often want to consider functions that are not defined everywhere, and by restricting ourselves to some domain, we gain a lot of flexibility.

Then we 'add' the interval (note that the connected open subsets of $\R$ are exactly the open intervals) to 'make space' for the variable $x$.
Every object of $\mathbb{I}\times \Omega$ can be written as $(x,z_1,\ldots, z_n)$, BUT NOT VICE VERSA. If $(z_1,\ldots, z_n)$ is not in $\Omega$, then $(x,z_1,\ldots, z_n)$ will of course not be in $\mathbb{I}\times \Omega$.

In general, there will be no 'good' description of $\Omega$, but in every case you are likely to come across it will be something like a disc or so. I would suggest doing some exercises, then you might see how the different parts of the definition fit together.

Answer (score 2):

The reason we set to RHS to zero is because we can always set it to be such. Consider for example the ODE
$$F(x,y,y')=x^3-yy''+y'=6$$
Of course however we can just move the $6$ over:
$$G(x,y,y')=x^3-yy''+y'-6=0$$
Since we can always do this it makes sense to only consider examples where $F=0$ for simplicity.

The reason $F$ can't be a constant function in $z_n$ (which is actually $y^{(n)}$) is because then it wouldn't be an $n$th order ODE, which contradicts our starting point. Consider the "third order" ODE
$$y''\sqrt{y'+y}+0\cdot y'''=0$$
Of course this is not actually third order.